# Why does Boa Hancock hate men?

Tags: one-piece

From what I've known, she is the only female member of the Shichibukai. She is also the "Snake Princess" of Amazon Lily.

**My question, why does Boa Hancock hate men? And more particularly, why is Luffy an exception?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boa Hancock and her sisters were enslaved and branded as slaves by the Celestial Dragons (Tenryuubito), this was a secret to everyone in Amazon Lily.

She loves Luffy because when Luffy was fighting her sisters (Marigold and Sandersonia) he kept the slave mark from being exposed to all people of the island.

[image]

Comment: Answered by Luffy himself. Lol

Answer (score 0):

The hate comes from her enslavement by the Celestial dragons. So far we have seen only two female Celestial dragons (from the human shop and Doffy's mom) so it's safe to assume that the majority of Celestial dragons who we got introduced to so far are male. Being surrounded by males who abused her and being raised by women who cherished her, as a child or teen she came to a conclusion that males are evil detestable creatures that only care about their satisfaction. Luffy on the other hand has no evil intentions as proven when he saw Hancock's naked body. Most males would have dirty thoughts but he didn't. Next, as Luffy was fighting the sisters he kept requesting the safety of Margaret and her friends who helped him. Also let's not forget the fact that he hid (well protect/cover) the sisters slave mark. As Luffy was still being tested to show his detestable male side, he was given only one choice: save the girls or given a boat. He must chose one and must abandon the other. Luffy did the unexpected and requested Margaret's safety. As the last trial (not really), Hancock told Luffy their story behind their slave mark (which he confused for the sun pirates mark). Hancock expected Luffy to detest her since she was once a slave but Luffy being he is says that he only hates the Celestial dragons. From then on, Hancock's heart was moved.